# I have installed Java 8, set environment variable and JAVA_HOME, but my system tries to find java.exe in wrong path, how do I correct it?

Tags: java

I have installed Java 8 and set my `JAVA_HOME` and `JRE_HOME` paths and added `%JAVA_HOME%` to the start of the path variable.
When I try to run simple java program I get error as
"The system cannot find the file `C:\spl\java\bin\bin\java.exe"`.
The above path contains extra bin.
Where as environment variable and `JAVA_HOME` has `C:\spl\java\bin\` this path.
I cannot understand from where this extra bin directory is coming.
Please help.
From where does system is taking `C:\spl\java\bin\bin\` this path?

Comment: What if you set `JAVA_HOME` to `"C:\spl\java"` **without** the `bin` on the end?

Comment: There is sometimes a definition that bases on other definition. So you have %JAVA_HOME%/bin at your path

Comment: The system looks in `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `JAVA_HOME` should point to the `...\Java\jdk1.8..` directory.

In Your `path` you should have `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`.

Some applications refer to `JAVA_HOME` and add `\bin` on their own, so you must not add `\bin` to your `JAVA_HOME`. Otherwise, you'll receive correct error saying, that `C:\spl\java\bin\bin\` doesn't contain Java.exe

**Solution:**
Remove `\bin` from your `JAVA_HOME`

Answer (score 0):

It is quite clear from your example: the system is taking `%JAVA_HOME%` as the "home" of your java installation, not its `bin` directory. So when you try to start `java.exe`, it looks in `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`. Just remove the `bin` part of your JAVA_HOME.